# Как реализовать обновление данных в React JS

Tags: reactjs

Только начинаю разработку на React JS. Хочу сделать следующее:

Сайт опрашивает внешний json файл, и если в нем есть новые или измененные данные - он добавляет новые и меняет измененные и отображает все на сайте.

Я сейчас не совсем понимаю, это разве на jQuery нужно делать бесконечный цикл который, например, раз в 2 сек будет обращаться к API для получения json? Но хотелось бы чтобы обращения были только тогда когда были изменения в json либо добавлены новые записи.

API построено на php, при обращении по url отдает json.

Comment: в вашем случае нужно постоянно опрашивать api, либо использовать вебсокеты, и тогда уже сервер сможет посылать сигналы на клиент

Comment: Рекомендую вдумчиво покурить вот этот раздел учебника по js:
https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax

Есть 3-4 принятых способа сделать это, сообщения от сервера-клиенту: polling (бесконечный цикл который вы описали), long-polling, server sent events, websockets.